# How to add label value to WHERE condition in ASP.NET SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, gridview

I am using `SqlDataSource` and `GridView` in ASP.NET to fetch and display data. It works for simple queries but i am not sure how to add `WHERE` condition by providing a value from label in same page. I tried the following but it wont work.

[image]

Here `label_status_ecnumber` is the username of the person currently logged in and it will be displayed as a label. Then his data will be fetched and displayed in `GridView` as he logs in.

Then i also tried storing the value in session as below,

```
Session["EC"] = text_status_username.Text;
```

Here `text_status_username` is the `TextBox` where the username is entered during login and this is stored in session. I tried again like below,

[image]

Both the methods above are not working. This is my first time working with `SqlDataSource` and i cant seem to find any guidance for this online. How can i do this? To add the label value to where clause in `SqlDataSource`?

Comment: you need to write required conditions  inside `WHERE clause` block.

Answer (score 0):

It has many solutions!

One of them is : 

set **Source Property** to **Control**.

By doing so, it will be solved.
be sure your table have any data and try it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERoEl.jpg